# Pinescript -Plot pivot high or low only when pivot candle meets specific condition

Tags: pivot, pine-script

[image]
Hi , i am trying to plot arrow up and down only on colored candle which has specific rsi and adx setting.

What i want it when there are only blue candles range and there is pivot high among those candle i need, green arrow up only on that candle, if even surrounding candle will be non blue color

Similarly for red arrow for yellow candles.
.
below is my pinscript code, sorry but this is my first coding script -

```
study(title="RSI+ADX",overlay = true, shorttitle="C123")


//rsi,pivot & adx input
src = close, len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
adxlen = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing")
dilen = input(14, title="DI Length")

lb = input(defval = 1, title="Left Bars")
rb = input(defval = 1, title="Right Bars")

mb = lb + rb + 1

src1 = close, dk1 = input(59.90, minval=1, title="Overbought")
src2 = close, dk2 = input(40.10, minval=1, title="Oversold")
src3 = close, dk3 = input(55, minval=1, title="Overb")
src4 = close, dk4 = input(45, minval=1, title="Overs")


h = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
l = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = l == 0 ? 100 : h == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + h / l))

dirmov(len) =>
    up = change(high)
    down = -change(low)
    truerange = rma(tr, len)
    plus = fixnan(100 * rma(up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0, len) / truerange)
    minus = fixnan(100 * rma(down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0, len) / truerange)
    [plus, minus]

  adx(dilen, adxlen) => 
    [plus, minus] = dirmov(dilen)
    sum = plus + minus
    adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adxlen)
    [adx, plus, minus]
    
Buy() => rsi > dk1
Sell() => rsi < dk2 

[sig, up, down] = adx(dilen, adxlen)
bnow = (Buy() and down < up)
snow = (Sell() and down > up)
b = (rsi > dk3)
s = (rsi < dk4)

 barcolor(bnow ? color(#00F7FF, 0) : snow ? color(#FFDE0A, 0) : na )


plotshape(iff(b and not na(high[mb]), iff(highestbars(mb) == -lb, high[lb], na), na),style = shape.triangleup, location = location.abovebar, color = #00FF00, size = size.tiny, offset = -lb)
plotshape(iff(s and not na(low[mb]), iff(lowestbars(mb) == -lb, low[lb], na), na), style = shape.triangledown, location = location.belowbar, color = #FF0000 , size = size.tiny, offset = -lb)
```

My problem is how to plot on those specific candles only, as when i use rsi and adx series as source , it misses out the single blue color pivot high candle as you can see in above picture

Answer (score 0):

Your code and your image don't match.
In your image there are BUY and SELL labels which are not in your code.
I tested your code, correct the syntax error and upgraded it to version 5, then I add a condition so that plotting the hig/low occurs only on blue or yellow candle :

```
(bnow or snow) and b and not na(high[mb]) ? iff_1 : na
```

[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='RSI+ADX', overlay=true, shorttitle='C123')


//rsi,pivot & adx input
src = close
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title='Length')
adxlen = input(14, title='ADX Smoothing')
dilen = input(14, title='DI Length')

lb = input(defval=1, title='Left Bars')
rb = input(defval=1, title='Right Bars')

mb = lb + rb + 1

src1 = close
dk1 = input.float(59.90, minval=1, title='Overbought')
src2 = close
dk2 = input.float(40.10, minval=1, title='Oversold')
src3 = close
dk3 = input.int(55, minval=1, title='Overb')
src4 = close
dk4 = input.int(45, minval=1, title='Overs')


h = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
l = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = l == 0 ? 100 : h == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + h / l)

dirmov(len) =>
    up = ta.change(high)
    down = -ta.change(low)
    truerange = ta.rma(ta.tr, len)
    plus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0, len) / truerange)
    minus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0, len) / truerange)
    [plus, minus]

adx(dilen, adxlen) =>
    [plus, minus] = dirmov(dilen)
    sum = plus + minus
    adx = 100 * ta.rma(math.abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adxlen)
    [adx, plus, minus]

Buy() =>
    rsi > dk1
Sell() =>
    rsi < dk2

[sig, up, down] = adx(dilen, adxlen)
bnow = Buy() and down < up
snow = Sell() and down > up
b = rsi > dk3
s = rsi < dk4

barcolor(bnow ? color.new(#00F7FF, 0) : snow ? color.new(#FFDE0A, 0) : na)


highestbars_1 = ta.highestbars(mb)
iff_1 = highestbars_1 == -lb ? high[lb] : na
plotshape((bnow or snow) and b and not na(high[mb]) ? iff_1 : na, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(#00FF00, 0), size=size.tiny, offset=-lb)
lowestbars_1 = ta.lowestbars(mb)
iff_2 = lowestbars_1 == -lb ? low[lb] : na
plotshape((bnow or snow) and s and not na(low[mb]) ? iff_2 : na, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(#FF0000, 0), size=size.tiny, offset=-lb)
```

Comment: Thank you, for quick reply, i saw the different images, let me provide the updated images

Comment: thank you for converting to version 5, if you check your images, you can see green arrow on brown candle or red arrow on black candle. so what i want it that pivot high/low arrow should occur only on blue/yellow coloured candle respectively .

Comment: @Npats I edited my answer, hppe it helps.